# Object is of type 'unknown' typescript about Promise

Tags: typescript, redux, types, react-redux, promise

I have a simple function that takes a function as it's argument and returns a new function. I get Object is of type 'unknown' when calling the returned function

```
export function fetchCount(amount: number) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve({ data: amount }), 500));
}

export const incrementAsync = createAsyncThunk('counter/fetchCount', async (amount: number) => {
  const response = await fetchCount(amount);
  return response.data; // red wave info under response
});
```

red wave info:const response: unknown Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)

Comment: I don't how to solve it with typescript without any type. help

Answer (score 1):

`Promise<T>` is a generic type and the type cannot be inferred in your case, so you'll need to provide that generic type argument:

```
export function fetchCount(amount: number) {
  return new Promise<{data: number}>(
    (resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve({ data: amount }), 500));
}
```